# WCF TCP transport binding - custom scheme?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, binding, tcp

I'm trying to provide a custom scheme for my custom TCP transport binding, however upon starting the service host, it'll always tell my that 'net.tcp' is expected:

```
public class MyTcpBinding: Binding
{

    private readonly MyTcpTransportBindingElement _transport;
    private readonly BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement _binaryEncoding;

    public override string Scheme
    {
        get { return "my.tcp"; }
    }

    public MyTcpBinding()
    {
        _transport      = new MyTcpTransportBindingElement();
        _binaryEncoding = new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement();
    }

    public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
    {
        return new BindingElementCollection(new BindingElement[]
        {
            _binaryEncoding, _transport
        });
    }
}

public class MyTcpTransportBindingElement : TcpTransportBindingElement
{
    public override string Scheme
    {
        get { return "my.tcp"; }
    }
}
```

What could be done to resolve this?